# How to put $N$ elements in $M$ cells separated by a distance $D$

Tags: combinatorics

I have tried to find an answer to similar problems but combinatorics is not my highest skill... So this is the thing: I have a set $\mathcal{M} = \{1,\dots,M\}$ and I have $N$ particles that I have to put in $\mathcal{M}$. The catch is that no two particles can be in positions closer than $D$. How can I solve this?

Another way of posing the problem is how many ways are there to put $N$ disjoint intervals of length $D$ in $\mathcal{M}=[1,M]$. But I have nothing.

Comment: You may find it helpful to ditch the "of course" constraint and make the answer 0 in that case. This allows you to write a recurrence...

Comment: Thanks @PeterTaylor, I'm on it. If I get something I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the problem around: you have $N$ particles, say $p_1,\ldots,p_N$ from left to right, and you have to insert a total of $M-N$ blank spaces in the slots before $p_1$, after $p_N$, and between $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,N-1$, in such a way that there are at least $D-1$ blanks between $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,N-1$. Blanks are indistinguishable, so an arrangement of particles and blanks is completely determined by the numbers of blanks in these $N+1$ slots. Start by putting $D-1$ blanks into each of the $N-1$ slots between adjacent particles; that uses up $(N-1)(D-1)$ blanks, leaving

$$(M-N)-(N-1)(D-1)=M-DN+D-1$$

blanks to be distributed arbitrarily amongst the $N+1$ slots.

Counting the ways to do this is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29), and it can be done in

$$\binom{(M-DN+D-1)+(N+1)-1}{(N+1)-1}=\binom{M-(D-1)(N-1)}N$$

ways. The reasoning behind the formula is explained reasonably well at the link.

Comment: Holy cow! I had not realized that I had to put $D-1$ blanks into each slot. You pointed out my eternal issue with combinatorics, turning the problem around. That's smart. Thanks!

Comment: @Duronman: You’re welcome!